# OwnCloud server can't load external storage folder content

Tags: linux, debian, owncloud

I have installed ownCloud 10.4 on my Debian 10 server running PHP 7.3, Apache 2.4.38 and MariaDB 10.3. OwnCloud seems to work fine, at least from its web UI.

I have a hard drive on my server mounted on `/mnt/data/` that I need to use as the ownCloud server storage space.

(I've been considering (and tried) to use a symlink from `/var/www/owncloud/data/user/files/symlink` to `/mnt/data/` but [it doesn't work](https://central.owncloud.org/t/how-to-make-owncloud-reading-filesystem-symlinks/1802).)

I have added `'files_external_allow_create_new_local' => 'true',` to ownCloud config file `config.php`, so I now successfully can add a local storage with ownCloud web UI.
I have changed permissions of `/mnt/data/` so that everything is now recursively owned by `www-data`, the Debian HTTP user used by ownCloud.

Under the "storage" section of ownCloud web UI admin settings, I can add a folder configured to be `/mnt/data/` (it shows a green circle), it will then appear on the user's web UI but saying there are no files in it, wether there are and I rescan using ownCloud `php occ files:scan --all` command.

Also, when I add a subfolder configured to be the existing subfolder on external disk `/mnt/data/subfolder`, it doesn't add it, showing a red square in the settings in web UI as an error. It also shows "*Some of the configured external mount points are not connected. Please click on the red row(s) for more information*" on top of ownCloud web UI.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, it was just a Linux permissions issue. In my case, www-data owning the external drive content wasn't sufficient, I needed to change the permissions rules to 755.

So `chmod -R 755 /mnt/data` did the trick.